# How to print php mysql query response message on front-end

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want to print mysql query response on front-end from the php script. For example from when the blow query will execute

```
mysql> UPDATE cl_time.outgoings SET amount=407481.24 WHERE outgoings.id=198;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

It will print `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0` on the front-end. Is there any mysql function to get this message?

Comment: Not directly but you can do yourself with `mysqli_num_rows()`

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows()` gives number of rows present in the result set you just selected. You can use `mysqli_affected_rows()` to find number of rows affected by your `insert`, `update` or `delete` query.

Comment: But it will only return the number of rows in result set. But for update query it will return 0 if we want to update the same value twice like if i have the amount=1000 and then i want to update it to amout=1000 again it will return 0

Comment: I want to check if the query was Ok or throws any errors with the numbers of rows affected to check either it was the updating same value in case of OK

Answer (score 1):

Try sending a ajax request(get) from the front-end to the back-end.

In the backend you will need to echo

```
echo mysql> UPDATE cl_time.outgoings SET amount=407481.24 WHERE outgoings.id=198;
```

and in the front-end

```
$.ajax({
   type: `GET`,
   url: `backend`,
   success: function(response){
      //place the data on the page
   }
)};
```